# Pricing multiple bonds in R using loop

Tags: r

I am new to R. I was trying to price 20 bonds using one function that I created which is as follows.I can use the `Bond_function(FV,coupon,y,freq,T_mat)` 20 times entering different values from csv. But I was hoping if I can loop it and stack all the data in a vector/matrix so that it can be done in one code instead of running it 20 times individually.
for example;  I tried

```
bond_1 <- Bond_function(100,2.75,2.88,1,2)
```

and did the same thing 20 times then assigned it to a data frame. I was trying to loop it 20 time directly from the csv file so that I can use one code and be done with it. maybe an apply function?

Need help with this. Thanks!

```
rm(list = ls())
Bond_function <- function(FV,coupon,y,freq,T_mat){
  y_d <- y/freq
  DF <- 1/(1+y_d/100)
  C1 <- sort(rep(1:T_mat,freq))
  C2 <- 1:T_mat*freq
  N_p <- length(C2)
  C3 <- rep(coupon/freq,N_p)
  C3[N_p] <- C3[N_p] + FV
  C4 <- DF^(1:N_p) * C3
  Bond_price <- sum(C4)
  C5 <- C4/Bond_price
  C6 <- C2/freq
  C7 <- C6*C5
  Macaulay_duration <- sum(C7)
  results <- c(Bond_price,Macaulay_duration)
  return(results)
}
```

FV and freq are fixed so I will be using the same value for each bond. However I have data available in a csv format that I would like to use for coupon, yield and T_mat. The data from csv is as follows.

```
   Number Coupon  Price Yield Maturity Period
1       1   2.75  99.74  2.88        2      1
2       2   2.88  99.11  3.07        5      1
3       3   2.88  97.00  3.23       10      1
4       4   3.00  92.47  3.40       30      1
5       5   1.50 100.06  1.47        2      2
6       6   1.50 100.50  1.40        5      2
7       7   1.63 100.55  1.56       10      2
8       8   2.25 104.28  2.06       30      2
9       9   1.13 101.57  0.31        2      3
10     10   1.13 103.25  0.46        5      3
11     11   1.50 106.20  0.85       10      3
12     12   2.00 114.17  1.42       30      3
13     13   0.13  99.95  0.15        2      4
14     14   0.25  99.45  0.36        5      4
15     15   0.63  98.19  0.82       10      4
16     16   1.38  94.69  1.60       30      4
17     17   0.13  99.93  0.16        2      5
18     18   0.75  99.42  0.87        5      5
19     19   1.13  95.19  1.66       10      5
20     20   1.88  90.48  2.32       30      5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is `T_mat` variable in csv?

You can use `mapply` here if the `T_mat` variable is `Period` object from the csv and your dataframe is called `df`.

```
result <- t(mapply(function(x, y, z) Bond_function(100, x, y, 1, z), df$Coupon, df$Yield, df$Maturity))
```

Comment: T_mat is the Maturity in csv. I'll try this thanks!

Comment: Hey, The code worked. Thanks! I've marked it.